# How do I set the order when querying from DB?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm trying to query from a DB to get joomla articles from a certain category (52), and that are published.

I want to return these as the newest created, but I don't know where to add in the ORDER BY for the query.

I did try to add `->orderby('created');` just above `$db->setQuery($query);` but that didn't seem to work, it still only seems to be displaying by ascending order of ID.

Can anyone help?

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();     
$query = $db->getQuery(true);     
$query->select('*')
->from('#__content')
->where('catid = 52 AND state = 1');    
$db->setQuery($query);     
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
    if(++$i > 1) break;
    echo "<li><a href='/why-us/news/".$row->id."-".$row->alias."'>".$row->title."</a></li>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Didn't work doesn't help your potentially helpers. Using SQL it was the right place. What do you expect, what do you get instead?

Comment: Well I expected the newest created articles to be shown, instead of ID order.

Comment: It's not `orderby` it's `order`. `->order('created asc');` [Just go through the documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase)

Comment: I'm still not sure that's working correctly. I had one article in this category, and it shows that fine. Added another article, expecting it to display that instead, but its still showing the first item. (older

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: You're right in everything but one. It should be `->order('created DESC');` to get the newest first.

Comment: @VMai Oops you're right, moving too fast over here.

Comment: Nice one guys. Who wants to be credited with the answer?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I never knew Joomla had anything like this, you never get any results of this when you search for stuff. It's all Wordpress codex. That's nice to know though!

Comment: Adding relevant tags would've gotten faster and more efficient results ;)

Comment: It's ok. I did start Googling at first, found what Ohgodwhy provided as a link, but wasn't entirely sure that was it. @Ohgodwhy should be credited for it.

Comment: That's what I was thinking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `->order('created DESC')` to achieve your desired results.

Check the [documentation page, here](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase)

Comment: +1 I'm going to remember that one ;) here I was looking for `orderby` I was close. I'll have to brush up on the SO many frameworks' syntax; that'll keep me busy for a while.